# How to make program get terminated by itself when nothing to read

Tags: c, bash, unix

I am running a C program using this script:

```
tail -f -n +1 input | ./output
```

and my program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

It should get terminated immediately after running because there is nothing to read in this program.

But what happens is, it does get terminated unless I give some input to the `input` I have used to redirect to my program.

Why, I am having this behaviour?

Comment: Press `Enter` if you want to fix this manually. Put `\n` in your string if you want your program to do that for you.

Comment: but i dont want to do this manually, and putting  \n dose not work.

Comment: I found the right answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404272/how-to-exit-early-on-pipe-close

Comment: It isn't quite clear what behaviour yiu want.

Comment: What do you mean by  *when nothing to read*? When there is nothing in the `input` file to read? or when the `output` program does not perform any read?

Answer (score 2):

> Why, I am having this behaviour?

`tail -f input` keeps reading `input` and does not close the pipe. When your program finishes, the pipe becomes *broken* because its *reading end* is closed (by your program).

If `tail` tries to write into the pipe it will receive `SIGPIPE` and will be killed. Otherwise `tails` hangs.

---

First, try to run `tail -f -n +1` separately on `stdin`:

```
$ tail -f -n +1
tail: warning: following standard input indefinitely is ineffective
```

By looking at the option `-f` in `tail`'s man page:

> `-f`, `--follow[={name|descriptor}]`
>    output **appended** data as the file grows;

So, just remove the `-f` option from the `tail` command:

```
tail -n +1 input | ./output
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill my requirement because in case program ask for input, it will read some garbage value.  i will need to follow that file because it is serving input to program in case it needs some input.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate further? Why do you need to follow? `tail -n +1 input` will write to the pipe up to the whole `input` file. Why do you say "garbage value" ?

Comment: actually i need to follow file because if there is some input required form user end i will give prompt to user on front end and if user give me some input , i will append it to my input file and so on.Thats why i need to follow that input file.

Comment: i found my answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416150/make-tail-f-exit-on-a-broken-pipe